# how do i remove array of elements in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to remove array of elements but it's not working at all..

in schema

```
var connectedUsers = Schema({
  fruits: { type: Array },
  vegetables: { type: Array }
})
var connectedusers = mongoose.model("connectedusers", connectedUsers)
```

Node js routing file

```
router.post('/connectedusers', function(req,res) {
connection.connectedusers.update(
        { $pull: { fruits: { $in: [ "apples", "oranges" ] }, vegetables: "carrots" } },
        { multi: true }
    )
    connection.connectedusers.find({}, function (err, docs) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json({
            docs: docs
        })
    })
});
```

In mongodb collection

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5cef68f690a42ba057760e98"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "connectArray": [
        "vinay",
        "vinay1"
    ],
    "fruits": [
        "apples",
        "pears",
        "oranges",
        "grapes",
        "bananas"
    ],
    "vegetables": [
        "carrots",
        "celery",
        "squash",
        "carrots"
    ]
}
```

Array of elements are not removing.. its showing all collection details.
how do i remove elements from mongodb using $Pull or any other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the match query also the db functions are [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Asynchronous) so you will need to [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) for the update operation to complete before querying to check if the db has changed, this can be done with [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```
// change callback to an async arrow function
router.post('/connectedusers', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // wait for this operation to complete before continuing
        await connection.connectedusers.update(
            {},
            { $pull: { fruits: { $in: [ "apples", "oranges" ] }, vegetables: "carrots" } },
            { multi: true }
        );
        // update complete now wait for the find query
        const docs = await connection.connectedusers.find({});
        // no errors, send docs.
        // if the variable name is the same as your field
        // that you want to send in the object you can just
        // pass that variable directly
        res.json({ docs });
    // catches errors from both update and find operations
    } catch (err) {
        // set the status code and send the error
        res.status(/* error status */).json(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
router.post('/connectedusers', function(req,res) {
connection.connectedusers.update(
        {},                   //  Missing query part
        { 
           $pull: { 
                 fruits: { $in: [ "apples", "oranges" ] }, 
                 vegetables: "carrots" 
           } 
        },
        { multi: true }
    )
    connection.connectedusers.find({}, function (err, docs) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json({
            docs: docs
        })
    })
});
```

Your query is working fine I tried it at my end. You were missing query part from MongoDB [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) function